# Proving arguments logically by inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I think I am on the right track but got stuck on 6.

1. $p ∨ (r ∧ t)$   **premise**
2. $¬p ∨ ¬(q ∧ u)$ **premise**
3. $(q ∧ u) ∨ s$ **premise**
4. $¬s$ **premise**
5. $(r ∧ t) ∨ ¬(q ∧ u)$ **1,2, Resolution**
6. $(q ∧ u)$ **3,4, Disjunctive Syllogism**

We have to prove that we can get to 
$r$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$7.\; \lnot \lnot (q\land u)\quad$ Double negation (6)

$8.\quad (r\land t)\qquad $ Disjunctive syllogism (5, 7)

$9.\quad r\qquad\qquad$ Simplification (8)

So we can *infer* (deduce) $r$, but that is not to say the premises are equivalent to $r$.

Comment: thanks, double negation totally slipped my mind. So you can only use Disjunctive syllogism when there is a negative sign in one of the arguments?

Comment: We can have $p \lor q$, $\;\lnot q$, and $\therefore p$. We can also have $p \lor \lnot q$, $\;q$, therefore $p$, but the double negation on $q$ is implied so that it is not (not q).

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I was wondering if you can take a look at another problem I had http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138402/express-the-quantified-logical-statements-using-the-predicates

Comment: Sure, I'll look it over, but give me a little time...can you wait until tomorrow?